# Labels such as Lemma 1B5 instead of Lemma 1.2.5. (avoiding all punctuation)

Tags: labels, counters

I wonder whether it is possible for LaTeX (or the amsthm package) to change the style of numbering of a Theorem, Lemma, Corollary, Definition, ... to something like Lemma 1B5 instead of Lemma 1.2.5. (avoiding all punctuation). This would be the 5th result in Section B of Chapter 1, for example. If it is feasible, then Lemma 1B5b could be part b of Lemma 1B5. This is a more compact style than Lemma 1.2.5.2. My failed attempt to achieve this is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\Alph{subsubsection}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Modules}
\section{Definition $R$-modules}
Let $R$ be a ring.
\begin{theorem} First Theorem\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\label{2}
  Second Lemma
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\rm (\alph*)}]
    \item part a
    \item part b\label{b}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}
It follows from Lemma~\ref{2}\ref{b} that \dots.

\section{Examples of $F[t]$-modules}
\begin{proposition} First proposition\end{proposition}
\begin{lemma} Second lemma\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE.JPEG]

Comment: What about section numbers? Should they have the format 1A (first section in the first chapter)?

Comment: @egreg Yes, that is correct. I added the output of my MWE so you can see section numbers so labeled.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\Alph{subsubsection}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\renewcommand\thetheorem{\thesection\arabic{theorem}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Modules}
\section{Definition $R$-modules}
Let $R$ be a ring.
\begin{theorem} First Theorem\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\label{2}
  Second Lemma
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\textup{(\alph*)}},ref=\alph*]
    \item part a
    \item part b\label{b}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}
It follows from Lemma~\ref{2}\ref{b} that \dots.

\section{Examples of $F[t]$-modules}
\begin{proposition} First proposition\end{proposition}
\begin{lemma} Second lemma\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you! Having Theorem 1A1 *First Theorem* without a period after 1A1 would be helpful for me. I saw this in another post, but couldn't replicate it. Also, should I define an environment \myenumerate which contains the label= and ref= options? Thanks again.

Comment: The last period is from the theoremstyle. See the amsthm documentation how you can define your own style.

Comment: Thanks. The amsthm examples file thmtest.tex gave a concrete example